# Build Farm says it can't Catkin

Tags: ros, catkin-package, buildfarm

[image: Rosanswers logo]

```
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:6 (catkin_package):
   Unknown CMake command "catkin_package".
```

http://jenkins.ros.org/job/ros-hydro-r2-gazebo_binarydeb_raring_i386/2/console

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/113151/build-farm-says-it-can%27t-catkin/) by [David Lu](https://answers.ros.org/users/19/david-lu/) on ROS Answers with karma: 10932 on 2013-12-26

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Your CMakeLists.txt file (https://github.com/brown-release/nasa_r2_simulator_release/blob/release/hydro/r2_gazebo/0.5.1-0/CMakeLists.txt) does not `find_package(catkin)` before it uses catkin specific functions like `catkin_package()`.

---

Originally posted by [Dirk Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/2575/dirk-thomas/) with karma: 16276 on 2013-12-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2